# VueJS usando a tag Name do pai nos filhos

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2

Segue um input de exemplo:

```
<input name="TESTE" id="TESTE" placeholder="TESTE">
```

Tem como eu fazer algo desse tipo para não repetir o mesmo nome varias vezes? 
Tipo isso abaixo:

```
<div name="TESTE">
    <input :name="parent.name" :id="parent.name" :placeholder="parent.name">
</div>
```

Eu não quero usar o `data` do vue, nem components, nem nada... Tem algum jeito de fazer isso usando o simples e puro *HTML* como o exemplo acima?

Obrigado!!!

Comment: Eu acho que se não usares essas coisas no Vue mais vale não usares Vue. O indicado aí seria mesmo definires isso na função `data` do componente

Comment: Vai ter que definir no `data` mesmo.

Comment: Ok então, obrigado!! =)